# Method of solving non-linear, first-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, transcendental-equations

I encountered the non-linear, first-order differential equation
$$
 y'^2 + \sin^2 y = f(x),
$$
where $f(x)$ is:
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin^2 x}{A + B\cos x + C\cos^2 x}
$$

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve the full equation, and whether even a closed-form solution is possible?

Comment: May be you need to solve the homogeneous part $(y')^2+\sin y=0$ first

Comment: Solving $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\sin y}} = -dx$, I get the solution in wolfram alpha that $x = c_1 - 2F(\frac{1}{4}(\pi-2 y)|2)$ where $F(x|m)$ is the elliptic integral of first kind with $m=k^2$ parameter. This looks difficult to find the inverse of. Do you think there's possible with a closed form solution of the full differential equation?

Comment: You should put this in the body of the question instead of comment.

Comment: The equation is not linear. Except as a special test case, it does not help to solve the homogeneous equation.

Comment: I'd try some trigonometric substitution, i.e. $u = \sin x, v = \sin y$, and see how it goes. Or the typical substitution using tangents so popular as a torture device when teaching integration.

Comment: I tried these, but to me there seems to be a problem that when differentiating with respect to $u$ left hand side, you get the jacobian determinant mixing in $u$, unless it's trivial, making it seemingly even less manageable... Would like a transformation that took $y'^2 \rightarrow \dot v^2 - \sin^2 y$.